# Azure Batch is deleting files from File Share

Tags: python, azure-batch

I have created a single Pool (size `Standard_D32_v3`) with a single Job. I have set the pool property `max_tasks_per_node=32`.
I then have a list which contains 27000 objects.
Since I cannot add more than 100 tasks at a time to a Job, I "Chunk" my list so that I have a list of lists, each with 100 tasks.
Finally, I insert each "Chunk" of tasks.

In the StartTask, I mount a File Share (Not BLOB), which contains files needed for processing.

My File Share has folders: 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017.

I have found that for some reason, Azure Batch is deleting all files & folders except for 2017. This the 2nd time it has happened.

**No where in my code do I delete from the file share or anywhere else.**

I do delete the Pool, Job and Tasks when finished.

What the *&^% is going on?

**UPDATE**

This is still happening.
When the File Share is mounted, it is done so via Bash as a command passed into the StartTask. Azure portal gives the connection information for the File Share and provides the following CHMOD configuration: `dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777'`

I thought that I would be clever and change CHMOD properties to 444 (read only).
Unfortunately, I then get a "Permission Denied" error. I then changed to 555 (read and execute) and files were once again deleted.

This is 100% an issue with Azure Batch. Microsoft does not do any logging what-so-ever (or even allow users to) of File Shares. I was hoping to see delete requests/operations and from which IP and time the request originated, but alas, it is impossible...

Comment: Where are you mounting the file share to?

Comment: @fpark to $AZ_BATCH_NODE_SHARED_DIR/data

Comment: What are you placing in `data`? The only thing I can think of is if you're somehow redirecting the task directories to the file share as Azure Batch cleans up tasks on delete.

Comment: I was mounting my File Share to that folder. I have tried creating and mounting to a different directory, but the same thing happens.... and it does not happen every time.

Comment: Do you have symlinks in your task directories that point to files in `data`?

Comment: Nope, just mounting the FS and then use the path stored in a DB to locate and read the files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156686/discussion-between-fpark-and-pookie).

Comment: Like this: `$AZ_BATCH_NODE_SHARED_DIR/data/path/to/my/file/myfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

A fix was deployed to all Azure regions on 2017-10-19 that should prevent this behavior from happening. You will need to redeploy your pool to get this fix - if you've already mounted something under `$AZ_BATCH_NODE_ROOT_DIR`, then it is recommended to remotely login to the node and unmount the device first prior to deleting the pool.

On a side note: it is not recommended to mount any resource under a task directory. Because task directories are cleaned up when deleted, this can lead to deletion of mounted resources.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have been mounting via the Pool StartTask. Regarding the `it is not recommended to mount any resource under a task directory.`, where would be the best place to mount? Is there an environment variable? Also, is there nothing that can be put in place to prevent the deletion of mounted resources? It seems dangerous that such behaviour exists.

Comment: By task directory I mean anything under `$AZ_BATCH_TASK_DIR` or `$AZ_BATCH_TASK_WORKING_DIR`. You should now be safe to mount items under `$AZ_BATCH_NODE_SHARED_DIR`.